# Deep RL: How often should retraining be done?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

As the headline suggests, how often should retraining be performed when using deep RL? I guess retraining after every action is too expensive? I also guess there is no specific number (e.g. after 1,000 actions or after one week), so which criteria is most helpful?

Answer (score 1):

In general, the common way to do it is indeed at every time step.

Whether this is expensive or not, I suppose it depends fully on your problem/computational means rather than on the algorithm.

That being said, there are special categories of methods that may admit other answers:

- off-policy and off-line methods: Those are equivalent to compiling a dataset and train on your own time, similar to supervised learning.
- Approaches that use Monte Carlo estimates (like policy gradients or monte carlo tree search): You need to collect trajectories and then you perform the updates/training step(s) when a trajectory finishes.
- Approaches that use target networks (like DQN or DDPG): The target networks are usually trained on a slower rate compared to the "principal" networks.
- Model-based approaches (like World Models): Such may have separate training periods for learning the environment dynamics and for constructing a policy.

There are most certainly more categories and a more fine-grained can be done but this list probably covers most cases.